# SignalR ignore invocations that don't exist on the client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

One of my SignalR clients that connects to a more universal hub only needs to invoke one method on the server. Issue is that the server sends invocations to the client. The client then throws an error because I dont listen to this invocation on the client.

E.g. is the error I see.

```
[05:54:56 ERR] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection] Failed to bind arguments received in invocation 'null' of 'DeviceStatus'.
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invocation provides 1 argument(s) but target expects 0.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindTypes(Utf8JsonReader& reader, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.ParseMessage(ReadOnlySequence`1 input, IInvocationBinder binder)
```

Is there any way to ignore all undefined methods on the client side? I really only need specific parts on my hub with this application. Also considering that I cant add new features without updating all of my clients..

Comment: [Hope below 3 github issues useful to you ?](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Adotnet+Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindTypes%28Utf8JsonReader%26+reader%2C+IReadOnlyList%601+paramTypes%29&type=issues)

Comment: Sadly not what I am looking for, I found this here just now https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8753 where the [reply](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8753#issuecomment-497514590) by a contributor just says to ignore/exclude the log message if unwanted... Seems to be the only way to actually do this, probably because it is seen as a bad practice to do so.

Comment: Ok, so take their advice and use it properly.

Comment: Yes, that would be the "best" thing to do, sadly I am building a API for third party apps to use aswell. Issue that arises here is that I then would need to make n-amount of hubs. Only because that application would only need this, the other one would only need this. That would be unmaintainable and definitely not a suitable solution for me.
For now I just went with, ignore the logs, I don't like it, but it seems to be the only thing I can do about it now.

Comment: Another idea I had was to sort of make a header or something, that only subscribes to certain invocations, so the client never receives those. Dont know if header would be the best option here to do that, but something like that... Kinda messy tho.